# Azure Function with Event Grid Trigger is getting called twice whereas it is being published only once from other azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function which has Event Grid Trigger. The publish to the event grid topic to which it has been subscribed to ( manually) is being done from another azure function.

When I running the azure function with code to publish to the function with event grid trigger, the below code gets executed once as I can see from the logger which displays "Publishing to event grid" only once as expected.

```
log.Info("Publishing to event grid");
client.PublishEventsAsync(topicHostname,GetEventsList(id).GetAwaiter().GetResult);
```

However, the function with Event Grid Trigger is getting called twice as I can see the below line printed twice in the azure function with event grid trigger

> 2019-09-27T14:43:16.130 [Info] Function started
>   (Id=dc1ed52a-016b-4b25-8ebf-ac533c3ea84b)

While the execution of the function is in progress, it again displays the below line:

> 2019-09-27T14:43:16.168 [Info] Function started
>   (Id=61edb64e-f6ed-4956-851f-59e16fb1dc4e)

My expectation is that "Function started" should come in the logs only once and not twice since the other function is doing publish to the event grid topic only once. What can be a solution to make sure that the function with event grid trigger is called only once?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you’re hitting the event grid retry policies.  Event Grid will automatically by default retry messages it thinks have failed in processing.  By default it waits 30 seconds for a response from the web hook, and if more than 30 seconds has passed it assumes it failed and may retry.  My assumption is that when you see it fire the second time, 30 seconds has elapsed and event grid is retrying the message.  The workaround for longer running functions is to have a queue in the middle.  Either Event Grid drops into a queue which functions triggers on, or the function triggers and drops in a queue (or kicks of a Durable Function Async orchestration) so that Event Grid gets an immediate “I got it” response while work continues in the background.